# Getting URL from firebase storage and setting it to an AVAudioPlayer always throws error (swift xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, url, firebase-storage, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to download a URL from Firebase storage and save it to an AVAudioPlayer

```
func loadAudio(post: CompPost, completion: @escaping (AVAudioPlayer) -> ())
    {
        let audioRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("cPosts").child(post.uid).child("Audio").child(post.mp3)
        audioRef.downloadURL
        { (url, error) in
            print("mp3filename: " + post.mp3)
            guard error == nil else
            {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return /**alert**/ }
            let audioURL = url
            print("url:" + audioURL!.absoluteString)
            do
            {
                try self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL!)
                completion(self.audioPlayer)
                print("THIS HAS LOADED")
            }
            catch
            {
                print("COULD NOT ASSIGN URL") /**alert**/
                //ERROR here that keeps on happening :(
            }
        }
    }
```

I know for a fact it's the correct file from storage, and that there's no error getting the url because of my print statements to check, however, for some reason there is an issue setting this URL to the contents of my AVAudioPlayer, `audioPlayer`

Comment: You should `print(error)` inside `catch` and actually see what the error is. You should also use `AVPlayer` instead of `AVAudioPlayer` when dealing with streaming from remote URLs unless you actually want to download the entire file first (which is what your current code will do, which will block the main thread)

Comment: `error` is from the `.downloadURL` function, which is nil (that part works). How do I print the error regarding the AVAudioPlayer in catch? Also, I specifically want to stream audio, what's the difference, cuz in order to stream it i have to download it first?

Comment: "How do I print the error" -- in your code, you have marked where you are saying the error occurs. Use `print(error)` there. In terms of the difference between streaming and downloading a file, streaming starts playing as soon as there's enough to start playback. Downloading will download the entire file first.

Comment: Whoops, im an idiot lol, I changed it to AVPlayer and it actually worked, so that's great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @jnpdx meant (I think is) - this way you can let iOS stream directly from the remote URL, without handling downloading the file yourself

```
func loadAudio(post: CompPost, completion: @escaping (AVAudioPlayer) -> ())
{
    let audioRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("cPosts").child(post.uid).child("Audio").child(post.mp3)
    audioRef.downloadURL
    { (url, error) in
        print("mp3filename: " + post.mp3)
        guard error == nil else
        {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return /**alert**/ }
        let audioURL = url
        print("url:" + audioURL!.absoluteString)
        do
        {
            **try self.audioPlayer = AVPlayer(url: audioURL!)**
            completion(self.audioPlayer)
            print("THIS HAS LOADED")
        }
        catch
        {
            print("COULD NOT ASSIGN URL - Error = /(error)") /**alert**/
            //ERROR here that keeps on happening :(
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. In general, it’s good to print the actual error in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
try self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL!)
```

try using this (note the try position):

```
 do {
    self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL!)
    completion(self.audioPlayer)
} catch {
    print("===> " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

you can of course use AVPlayer as well (without the do/catch)

Comment: This will block the main thread until the file is completely downloaded.

Comment: as mentioned, `you can use AVPlayer as well`